Military and Strategy smart and clever female lead winning wars
I stumbled on a book recommendation on youtube that I can no longer find. The plot is about a female lead I believe was discovered or hired (I cannot remember) by the male lead ( I think) and she was the strategist for the war. It was set on a time where swords and knights existed. It was a series of books Trilogy or more.
The book recommended alongside it were

Graceling
Sabriel
Crown Duel
Daughter of smoke and bone
Winner's curse

Somewhat the same genres to these I have mentioned.

What SF aspect/s were present in the book?

Mary Gentle's Ash: A Secret History? One huge book published in 4 volumes in the US starring a female mercenary captain who's supernaturally skilled.

Not the one you're looking for, but it does remind me a bit of a Star Wars Expanded Universe book, which had a brief aside talking about Daala's skill as a naval strategist, and Grand Moff Tarkin's detective work to track her down, then defying the misogynist planetary government to promote her directly to Admiral.

Thank you everyone who participated to help. I was able to find the book. Edited the original post. I appreaciate your replies in helping me.

@Raff Please post an answer instead of editing the answer into your question.

Raff, feel free to copy and paste and or all of the placeholder answer I posted in your own answer and we'll then delete it. You will get points when your post is upvoted. You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Providing a placeholder answer that the querent found the answer to be The Girl of Fire and Thorns by Rae Carson.


Once a century, one person is chosen for greatness.
Elisa is the chosen one.
But she is also the younger of two princesses, the one who has never done anything remarkable. She can't see how she ever will.
Now, on her sixteenth birthday, she has become the secret wife of a handsome and worldly king—a king whose country is in turmoil. A king who needs the chosen one, not a failure of a princess.
And he's not the only one who seeks her. Savage enemies seething with dark magic are hunting her. A daring, determined revolutionary thinks she could be his people's savior. And he looks at her in a way that no man has ever looked at her before. Soon it is not just her life, but her very heart that is at stake.
Elisa could be everything to those who need her most. If the prophecy is fulfilled. If she finds the power deep within herself. If she doesn’t die young.
Most of the chosen do.

